# Data not syncning if Google Fit not installed on device

Tags: android, google-fit

I am using the Google Fit History API. It's working fine and I am inserting steps.

```
// Create a data set
int stepCountDelta = 950;
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);

// For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data value -- in this case,
// the number of new steps.
DataPoint dataPoint =
        dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(stepCountDelta);
dataSet.add(dataPoint);
// [END build_insert_data_request]
```

Now the response is returning success, but when I check on the [Google Fit dashboard](https://fit.google.com/fit/u/0/) it's not receiving the data and the data is not syncing from my app with Google Fit. How can I get the sync data? Currently the Google Fit default app is not installed on our device.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the Google Fit default app to sync and receive the data.

You can follow the steps below:

> 1. Download **Google Fit** from the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness)
>      to the watch.
> 2. Open **Google Fit** on your watch.
> 3. Complete the initial setup.

Now your watch can be used to collect your fitness data, and it will be automatically synced to Google Fit. You can probably see your records in the dashboard.

You can check this [blog](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-sync-your-fitness-band-google-fit) for more details.

Comment: means without downloading GoogleFit app, i cant sync data from my app to google fit dashboard?

Comment: If you want to sync you're data, you must download GoogleFit App. It is a must :)